# Android. Dynamic class loading and Java interfaces

Tags: android

I've almost finished my first real Android project, a taxi ordering application, only some little usability concerns are left. For future releases we plan to implement built-in automatic updates of programming code and resources like some good programs do. I managed to run a simple example, based on http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html, [How to load a Java class dynamically on android/dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik) and [Is it possible to dynamically load a library at runtime from an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicat?rq=1). I will not post here complete code, it looks much like over the links above. Main apk acts as launcher, it loads a jar-file from SD-card, loads a special class from there, instantiates an obect and calls its method via Java Reflect API, that simply brings up ab AlertDialog.

But I want to be able to use common base Java interfaces both in launcher and in loaded library, acting as API. So I tried to declare an inteface called Problem both in launcher and library. The code is like this:

```
Class<?> problemClass = cl.loadClass("ru.homez.euler.Problem1");
Problem problem = (Problem)problemClass.newInstance();
problem.solve(this);
```

Dalvik VM doesn't like this, i get

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved
>   to unexpected implementation

I think this happens due to that Problem interface is defined both in launcher and library, I have seen issues like that here. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

I was lucky to find this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698049/how-to-dynamically-load-a-jar-with-‌​common-abstract-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698049/how-to-dynamically-load-a-jar-with-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcommon-abstract-class). I stripped interface off from the library jar, and in loader I changed its availability to public (library class loader doesn't see package-available classes loaded with apk)! Problem solved!